# Magento Success/Failure Message for the Form Submission using Javascript

Tags: magento2, javascript, messages

I am submitting the form to edit primary shipping and billing addresses via ajax (2 forms, 1 page), and it finally works like it has to. Now, I'd just like to add messages that Magento sets for those forms, to display as soon as the form is submitted, without page reload.
Can I retrieve those messages somehow with javascript?

If not, how do I disable setting the messages for editing primary shipping and billing addresses forms? Because now the messages don't show on the same page, but when I visit another page, they show up.

Much appreciated,

- Magento newbie